# Read Blob to picture box in VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, blob, picturebox

I messed around with this quite a bit and tried to follow every other example on the web but I just can't seem to pull a blob image out of a MySql DB to a picture box.  Eventually I would like to be able to display a picture in a picturebox and give the user the ability to save the picture to their computer with the save as dialog.  This is what I have so far and my error is  when I try to actually put the picture in the picture box at "picShowPicture.image = Image.FromStream"  any help would be appreciated.

```
    Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Drawing
    Imports System.Drawing.Imaging
    Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Windows.Forms

    Dim cn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim constring As String
    constring = "server=localhost;User Id=uid;password=pass;database=default"

    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim cmdtxt As String
    cmdtxt = "SELECT picture FROM test WHERE serial = '" & txtSerial.Text & "'"
    With cmd
        .Connection = cn
        .CommandText = cmdtxt
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    End With

    cn.ConnectionString = constring
    cn.Open()

    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "test")
    Dim c As Integer = ds.Tables("test").Rows.Count
    If c > 0 Then
        Dim bytBLOBData() As Byte = _
            ds.Tables("test").Rows(c - 1)("picture")
        Dim stmBLOBData As New MemoryStream(bytBLOBData)
        picShowPicture.Image = Image.FromStream(stmBLOBData)
    End If
```

Comment: What is the actual error you get?

Comment: Argument Exception was Unhandled, parameter is not valid.